# Is it possible to add some text or some tag under below the create user wizard steps button (previous, next, finish, etc) in createuserwizard??

Tags: asp.net, .net

```
enter code here`<asp:WizardStep ID="CreateUserWizardStep0" runat="server" StepType="Start">
              <h1>Bir Hesap Seçin</h1>
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <asp:Label ID="AccountNameLabel" CssClass="grey" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="SearchAccount" > 
              Kullanıcı Adı:</asp:Label>
                </td>               
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <asp:TextBox ID="SearchAccount" CssClass="field" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator Visible="true" ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ControlToValidate="SearchAccount" Display="None" ValidationGroup="kayitFormu"  runat="server" ErrorMessage="Girmiş Olduğunuz Hesap Adı Kullanımdadır. Lütfen farklı bir hesap adı deneyiniz."></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                  </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <asp:Label ID="SearchAccountMessage" style="width:400px;" runat="server" ForeColor="red" />
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>

       </asp:WizardStep>`
```

Is it possible to add some text or some tag  under below the create user wizard steps button (previous, next, finish, etc) in createuserwizard??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the `StepNavigationTemplate`. This [site](http://weblogs.asp.net/grantbarrington/archive/2009/11/04/adding-changing-amp-finding-buttons-in-the-asp-net-wizard-control.aspx) should help

Comment: I'm glad to hear that, let us know whether this resolves your question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but you can use the navigation templates:

```
<StartNavigationTemplate>
    <asp:Button ID="btnStepNext" runat="server" Text="Next" Width="110" CommandName="MoveNext" CausesValidation="true" />                                                 
</StartNavigationTemplate>               
<StepNavigationTemplate>                   
    <asp:Button ID="btnStepPrevious" runat="server" Text="Previous" Width="110" CommandName="MovePrevious" CausesValidation="false" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnStepNext" runat="server" Text="Next" Width="110" CommandName="MoveNext" CausesValidation="true" />                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
</StepNavigationTemplate>
<FinishNavigationTemplate>                                                                          
    <asp:Button ID="btnStepPrevious" runat="server" Text="Previous" Width="110" CommandName="MovePrevious" CausesValidation="false" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnStepFinish" runat="server" Text="Finish" Width="120" CommandName="MoveComplete" CausesValidation="true" />                                                                           
</FinishNavigationTemplate>
```

Comment: Hi @James; Problem is  I need to use CreateUserWizard_NextButtonClick event to check username is available in codebehind but when I  used the navigaytion template how can I handle NextButtonClick event ??